# PyQt: Dialog's Minimize Window Button is Missing in OSX

Tags: python, pyqt, qtcore

A dialog created with:

```
class GUI(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()

global dialog
dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
myGui = GUI()
```

is missing a minimize window button (OSX). It is there in Windows. Do I have to set some flag to display this missing controller? Please advise, Thanks in advance!

## EDITED LATER:

I didn't try to solve a no-minimize-button issue with QtGui.QDialog(). But it appears I partically aware how to get that missing button using QtGui.QMainWindow.
Here is the simplest code illustrating a basic syntax:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        myQWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        myBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()       

        myLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit("myLineEdit")
        myBoxLayout.addWidget(myLineEdit)

        myQWidget.setLayout(myBoxLayout)

        self.setCentralWidget(myQWidget)


window = MainWindow()
window.show()
window.resize(480,320)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

A 'key' 'concept' behind QtGui.QMainWindow is that first we declare QWidget()

```
myQWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
```

to which we assign a 'main' layout:

```
myQWidget.setLayout(myBoxLayout)
```

Last step not to forget is to assign this QWidget() to dialog itself using:

```
self.setCentralWidget(myQWidget)
```

where 'self' is an instanced subclass of QtGui.QMainWindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QtGui.QDialog` does not offer a minimize button on any platform, but `QtGui.QMainWindow` does offer on each platform (Windows, Linux and OSX). You are creating a `QDialog` object and at the same time an object of `GUI` which is subclass of `QMainWindow`.  If you write `myGui.show()` the window will offer you all three buttons (minimize, maximize/restore and close). But in case of `dialog.show()`, you will not have two of them (minimize and maximize/restore). It's Qt's limitation.

Comment: It appears QtGui.QMainWindow comes with a layout that already "pre-build-in" . I wonder what syntax needs to be used to connect the widges to QtGui.QMainWindow?

Comment: No, `QMainWindow` doesn't contain a layout, it contains only a centralWidget (QWidget), you can add a layout to centralWidget `self.centralWidget.setLayou(someLayout)` then add widgets to `someLayout`, using `someLayout.addWidget(someWidget)`

Comment: This is all totally wrong. Qt most certainly does allow a minimize button for QDialog on both Linux and Windows. For Linux, all three buttons are available by default (I only tested with Openbox WM, though), and for WinXP they can be switched on using the `WindowMinimizeButtonHint` or `WindowMinMaxButtonsHint` flag.

Comment: Thanks guys! It seems with your help I was able to figure it out. Please see the edit to my original post...

Comment: Just came across the fact that .reject() method is not implemented for QtGui.QMainWindow (as it does for MainWindow() ). What would be a closest alternative to reject() (I mostly link it to Cancel button action)..

Answer (score 11):

I can't test this myself, but you could try setting these [window flags](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowType-enum):

```
    dialog.setWindowFlags(dialog.windowFlags() |
        QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint |
        QtCore.Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint)
```

(The `WindowSystemMenuHint` flag may not be necessary).

Comment: this is awesome, solved my problem with dialog.setWindowFlags(dialog.windowFlags() |
        QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint ). actually I tried to leave out dialog.windowFlags() but then the widget became quite weird without a title bar, would be good if you could advise what happened in that case. Thanks indeed tho!