# PyQt4 Child Windows do NOT minimize to Windows taskbar

Tags: python, windows-7, pyqt4, taskbar, minimize

Whenever I create a PyQt4 application with secondary (child) windows they do not minimize to the Windows 7 taskbar. Only the main (parent) window shows up on the taskbar. When a child window is minimized it collapses to the bottom of the screen with only the titlebar (and titlebar buttons) showing. Here is some sample code to demo this behavoir:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Parent(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Parent, self).__init__(parent)
        w = QtGui.QWidget()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(w)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Create Child')
        self.text = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        self.setWindowTitle('Parent')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.createChild)

    def createChild(self):
        self.dialog = QtGui.QMainWindow(self)
        #self.dialog.setParent(None)      
        self.dialog.setWindowTitle('Child')
        self.dialog.show()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
p = Parent()
p.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The only way I get my pyqt apps to behave the way I want is to set the parent of the children windows to None.

```
self.dialog.setParent(None)
```

Doing so makes keeping track of the children windows a lot more complicated than I feel it should be. Closing the main window does not close the secondary windows for example. With extra code this can work but it seems odd to have to break the parent relationship. Am I missing something?

Comment: You should have a look here at the answer first... http://stackoverflow.com/a/22203932/2436483

Comment: I do not have a problem getting my windows to minimize its the way the child windows hover when they are minimized that is my problem.

Comment: I would like the child window to collapse to the windows7 taskbar.